# Ionic2 Android deployment

Tags: ionic2

I am using a MAC machine with Java 9. While deploying my ionic2 app, System returns following error:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1)
```

My java version is great than 1.8 but system still returning me above error. Please advise.

Comment: i have been on this mistake, i can resolve uninstall and install again, after we have to check if the global variables are true

Comment: @HenriqueYC: Sorry couldn't understand your point. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: yeah, proib uninstall all and reinstall again first step

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Comment: im so happy for you, i hope you send one like to my comment

Comment: @HenriqueYC could you please add that as an answer (maybe including the exact commands or some more information) so we can then close this question? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @sebaferreras isnt necesary to set commands, only find the program java and uninstall and reinstall